# How to capture first line from XML response in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I am receiving an XML response from an API in a variable r so that:

```
print r.read()
```

displays the entire XML response.

I need to take the first line of this response and convert it to a string variable for use in a loop after some substringing. What is the best way to capture just the first line?

Comment: Wouldn't `r.read()` give you the whole string, which you could split by line breaks?  (I never used python but I expect you could loop through each character until you reach a line break character if you must...)

Comment: I think thats a good idea. The whole response is well over 100 lines so I thought taking the first line would be simpler. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The API call returns the whole XML, unless it's giving you the string as a stream, so internally you're processing the whole 100 lines anyways, but chown's solution is less work on your part (although run-time would be the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r.readline()`

[Built-in Types - File Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline):

> `file.readline([size])`
>   Read one entire line from the file. A trailing
>   newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file
>   ends with an incomplete line). If the `size` argument is present and
>   non-negative, it is a maximum byte count (including the trailing
>   newline) and an incomplete line may be returned. When `size` is not 0,
>   an empty string is returned only when EOF is encountered immediately.
>
> ```
>    r.readline()
>    'This is the first line of the file.\n'
>    r.readline()
>    'Second line of the file\n'
>    r.readline()
>    ''
> ```

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought also. I did try 'print r.readline()' but I got a UnicodeDecodeError: and thought that would not work.                      
Here is the whole thing. UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii', '\xef\xbb\xbf<list Action="Query" pageNumber="1" pageCount="213" pageRecordCount="100" totalRecordCount="21208" xmlns="http://www.site.com/API/Gateway">\r\n', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)'

Comment: Do I need to add some conversion? Also, how do I assign r.readline() to a variable for further use? resp = r.readline()?

Comment: Yea, `line1 = r.readline()` would do it.  You also may need to decode/encode the returned string before printing it.  See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html and http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/codecs/.  Or try opening the file with `codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8", ..)`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll go through that and give it a shot.

Comment: Can I use the codec on the object containing the complete XML response? That way I can do it without writing it to a file. Sorry if this is a super obvious answer

Comment: Sure, dont need codecs for that though.  Try: `utf_resp = resp.decode("utf-8")` then `ascii_resp = utf_resp.encode("ascii", "ignore")`, and you can `print ascii_resp` without the `UnicodeDecodeError` exception.

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you for the explanation and resources. Great learning experience for me. You rock.